# children are not shown belonging to parent element

Tags: jquery

On url: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/143355/datepicker/datepicker.html
  focus on `Date range`, you will see a date-picker widget.
  The code to generate this is as below:

```
var $months = this.nav('months', 1); //nav some function
    var $years = this.nav('years', 12);

    var $nav = $('<div>').addClass('nav').append($months, $years);

    this.$month = $('.name', $months);
    this.$year = $('.name', $years);

    $calendar = $("<div>").addClass('calendar');

    // Populate day of week headers, realigned by startOfWeek.
    for (var i = 0; i < this.shortDayNames.length; i++) {
      $calendar.append('<div class="dow">' + this.shortDayNames[(i + this.startOfWeek) % 7] + '</div>');
    };

    this.$days = $('<div>').addClass('days');
    $calendar.append(this.$days);

    this.$picker = $('<div>')
      .click(function(e) { e.stopPropagation() })
      // Use this to prevent accidental text selection.
      .mousedown(function(e) { e.preventDefault() })
      .addClass('datepicker')
      .append($nav, $calendar)
      .insertAfter(this.$el);
```

So, `$nav` and `$calendar` are children of `$picker`.

But if you inspect this widget in FF or chromium the elements appended to calendar: shortDayNames and `this.$days` they does not highlight in the calendar's area.

[image]

I want to extend this widget to add time support, but this problem blocks my way.
  **When I add one more div to this.$picker all these calender elements are shown in this new
  div instead of calender**.

[image]

code is as below:

```
var $hours = this.nav('hours', 0);
var $minutes = this.nav('minutes', 0);

var $timenav = $('<div>').addClass('nav').append($hours, $minutes);
this.$picker.append($timenav)
```

due to the problem stated above when I apply border-top to $timenav it shows above days, whereas I want it to appear below all days
  here is the image of result:

[image]

Is there some way to come out of this? does `.append()` creating any problem?

Comment: `$el`? shouldn't that be a reference to an element? near on the line where you have `insertAfter($el)`

Comment: this.$el is initialized in the constructor of the plugin as: this.$el = $(element); //element is input on which datepicker is initialized.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a css problem.
  Adding following property to .calendar class, solved problem:

```
overflow: hidden;
```

And Here is resultant image:see border on correct place

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Did you tried to search for already existing plugins which appends timepicker to jQuery .ui Date Picker plugin?

Please visit [Adding a Timepicker to jQuery Date Picker plugin](http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/).

I hope this will help you.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion but question is not about options available for timepicker, I want to extend bootstrap datepicker.